# Remove line spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

How can I remove the line spaces but without remove the structure of the next string.

```
    P0:::inicial
    P1:::pregunta
    P2:::pregunta
    P3:::pregunta
    R1:::respuesta
    R2:::respuesta
    R3:::respuesta
    R4:::respuesta
    R5:::respuesta
    R6:::respuesta
    R7:::respuesta
    R8:::respuesta
    R9:::respuesta
    C1:::cotizacion
    C2:::cotizacion
    C3:::cotizacion
    A1:::agregar
    A2:::agregar
                         <------ I want delete this spaces.
    C4:::cotizacion
```

I try using regex but I have problems when the regex and replace remove all the spaces on my string but I only want delete the spaces without information.

In try some like this:

```
replace(/[\r\n]+/g, " ");
```

Comment: /^\s*$(?:\r\n?|\n)/gm try with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with anchor and MULTILINE flag:

```
.replace(/^[ \t]*[\r\n]+/gm, "")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RpDQbA/1)

- `MULTILINE` or `m` mode makes `^` match start of each line.
- `^`: matches start of a line
- `[ \t]*`: Match 0 or more spaces or tabs
- `[\r\n]+`: Match 1+ line break characters `\r` or `\n`

Comment: Isn't `\s` the preferred Regular expression for Space?

Comment: `\s` also matches new lines not just horizontal spaces.

Comment: So yeah, `/^[\s]*[\r\n]+/m` That's what I thought, also the `g` is not necessary since the CR and the LF...

Comment: `g` is required if there are more blank lines like this in input. Also `^[ \t]*[\r\n]+` is more efficient than `^[\s\t]*[\r\n]+` because `\s` matches all kind of spaces. In fact `[\s\t]` can be changed to just `\s`

Comment: @anubhava yes, I forgot to remove the `\t` (done now ;))